# Ubuntu terminal unable to take in input and read directories

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-22.04

I did a certain angular command on my terminal(was ng common I think), Now my terminal isnt able to take any input. I use Ubuntu 22.04.

I was trying to run a project locally and angular was suggesting some commands to use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.